# plutus-playground-server sense of time is incorrect

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I think my `plutus-playground-server` has an incorrect notion of time. I'm working on the homework for lecture 3 and keep running into issues with the simulator.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm simulating for homework 2 of week 3:

[image]

I've verified that, according to the cabal repl, `1596059101000` is slot 10.

```
Prelude Ledger Wallet.Emulator Data.Default Ledger.TimeSlot Week03.Homework2> slotToBeginPOSIXTime de
f 10
POSIXTime {getPOSIXTime = 1596059101000}
```

Note that in the example simulation I `Wait Until Slot 11`.

I've changed the following line when constructing transactions clientside to `show now`: https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/commit/4098f73bef4191ebc976fb8c2c3d46ee53f97b5e#diff-7fd9bde64b988d6aa9520167ed285990ed737f5dbda967ac19c786ff4160bb36R105

Interesting, when I execute the above simulation, I see the following output:

```
Add slot 11
Contract instance for wallet 2: (ReceiveEndpointCall (EndpointDescription { getEndpointDescription: "grab" }) (RawJson "{\"contents\":[{\"getEndpointDescription\":\"grab\"},{\"unEndpointValue\":[]}],\"tag\":\"ExposeEndpointResp\"}"))
Contract instance for wallet 2: (ContractLog (RawJson "no gifts available at time POSIXTime {getPOSIXTime = 1596059102}"))
```

Note that the value of `now` is `1596059102` which is missing three trailing zeroes compared to `1596059101000`. If I check the posix time of slot 11 in the `cabal repl` I see

```
Prelude Ledger.TimeSlot Data.Default Week03.Homework1> slotToBeginPOSIXTime def 11
POSIXTime {getPOSIXTime = 1596059102000}
```

which is the value reported by the simulation with 3 extra trailing zeroes.

Does my instance of the `plutus-playground-server` have a "incorrect" notion of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is typical, I figured out what's wrong almost immediately after posting the question. I was on the wrong commit for my local checkout of the plutus repo. I was using commit `ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4` which comes from the [week 1 `cabal.project` file](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/cabal.project#L28).

The [week 3 `cabal.project` file](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week03/cabal.project#L28) requires `plutus` at commit `219992289c6615e197069d022735cb4059d43229`. After I made that change, the issue resolved itself.